# Does the "on" in front of "landing" indicate a very short time when something happened, which refers to "broke my back" here?

Tags: word-usage

I am aware that [landing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/landing) means

> the fact of an aircraft arriving on the ground or a boat reaching land

"landing **on** the ground" is a typical usage, for example

> The plane made a safe **landing on** Lake Michigan beach.

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/NHTJPd7cnBU?t=104) (a video link with a time stamp) (sentence_1)

> In Africa, my parachute ripped at 17,000 [feet].
>   I blacked out, and **on** landing broke my back.

The official transcript fits what I heard, there is an "on" in front of "landing".

the question is,

Does the "on" in front of "landing" indicate a very short time when something happened, which refers to "broke my back" here? If yes, could someone give more examples about this meaning of "on", such as **on time**?

I'm a bit confused, It seems that **on landing ** plays a role of subject.

on landing [subject] broke [verb] my back [object].

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*On landing* is quite different from *landing on*; it means 'at the moment that I landed'. See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on , (the last two examples under **used to show when something happens**.

*On time* is just a set phrase meaning 'not late'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is my analysis "on landing [subject] broke [verb] my back [object]" correct, in particular, **on landing ** plays a role of subject?

Comment: No, definitely not. _On landing_, as the dictionary says, **shows when it happened**. (Of course, common sense tells us that it was the hard landing that caused the injury, but that isn't what the sentence says.)

Comment: So, what is playing the role of subject in that sentence?

Comment: It was the speaker who broke his back, so 'I' is the subject!

Comment: I guess I've got the point. Just for sure, I rewrote the sentence as "I blacked out, and I broke my back on landing", is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what the speaker meant.

Answer (score 0):

I invite other people to comment on this and perhaps qualify or improve this, but…

I am thinking that there is something present in the expression “on {event}… ” that is not present in “when {event}… ” — being the idea that something (usually bad) was already inevitable or had already happened.  Some examples.

As above in the parachute story, {the person breaking their back} was inevitable (or very likely) from when the parachute got ripped.

“I was enjoying the holiday very much until, on arriving in Denmark, I discovered that I had left the ticket in Germany.”

“On reaching into his pocket for a cigarette, John discovered that it had a small hole in it — a hole probably big enough for a roll of film to fall through.  Frantically, he searched his other pockets.”

(Of course, one does not *have* to use “on…” for this idea; e.g., “It was only when he was turning the key in his front door that it occurred to Paul that Sharon might have thought that the package was a present for her.”  Conversely, that is a subtly different idea.)

I could add more examples, but I think the idea is fairly clear… and I am entertaining the possibility that I have missed part of the picture (in my thinking).